# Typo3v11 Upload files from frontend with custom Extension (extension builder)

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-11.x, extension-builder3

i created a custom extension with extensionBuilder and have a modal with a file attribute, I can create a new record with any file from backend, but i need to add the same functionality in frontend as well and couldn't find a solution

I tried simply putting a file tag in the form

```
<f:form.upload name="file" property="file" />
```

but got this error

```
Exception while property mapping at property path "file": The identity property "Screenshot from 2024-01-05 14-44-55.png" is no UID.
```

this is my createAction in my controller

```
public function createAction(\..\..\Domain\Model\Announcements $newAnnouncements) {
    $this->announcementsRepository->add($newAnnouncements);
    $this->redirect('list');
}
```

this is my tca if needed

```
'file' => [
        'exclude' => true,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:../Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_.._domain_model_announcements.file',
        'config' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig(
            'file',
            [
                'appearance' => [
                    'createNewRelationLinkTitle' => 'LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:media.addFileReference'
                ],
                'overrideChildTca' => [
                    'types' => [
                        '0' => [
                            'showitem' => '
                            --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                            --palette--;;filePalette'
                        ],
                        \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_TEXT => [
                            'showitem' => '
                            --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                            --palette--;;filePalette'
                        ],
                        \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_IMAGE => [
                            'showitem' => '
                            --palette--;;imageoverlayPalette,
                            --palette--;;filePalette',
                        ],
                        \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_AUDIO => [
                            'showitem' => '
                            --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                            --palette--;;filePalette'
                        ],
                        \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_VIDEO => [
                            'showitem' => '
                            --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                            --palette--;;filePalette'
                        ],
                        \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_APPLICATION => [
                            'showitem' => '
                            --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                            --palette--;;filePalette'
                        ]
                    ],
                ],
                'foreign_match_fields' => [
                    'fieldname' => 'file',
                    'tablenames' => 'tx_**_domain_model_announcements',
                    'table_local' => 'sys_file',
                ],
                'maxitems' => 1
            ]
        ),
        
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this article](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/exceptions/main/en-us/Exceptions/1297759968.html#exception-while-property-mapping-at-property-path-propertyname-the-identity-property-is-no-uid) in the TYPO3 documentation will help you.

Confirm that your controller action includes validation for file uploads. You may need to adjust the createAction method to handle file uploads correctly.